# What makes an Android App compatible with Tablet? [2020]

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, tablet

I've seen a couple of questions like this but they are all pretty old.

**Background**

I'm developing a Tracking App using Google Maps, that tracks users movements, calculates traveled distance, etc.

It must be compatible with Tablet; however, I do not own an Android tablet, and none of the available Tablet Virtual Devices on Android Studio have the Play Store option, so I'm not sure I can test it.

**Questions**

1. Will the Tablet virtual devices without the Play Store option be able to use the Google Maps functionality? If not, how can I make it so?
2. What else must I include in the App to make it compatible with Tablet?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't need to do anything to make an app compatible with tablets. Just make sure a. you don't rely on SIM cards and b. the app layout looks ok on big screens with low pixel density